# Why does java support both arrays and collections?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

In Python, I used lists to store collections while In Java there is more than one choice.
If java only supported Collections, would there be an issue?

Comment: @SudhirOjha That doesn't answer why java has both arrays and collections

Comment: @NikosTzianas Collections can not store primitives that's why java having both array and Collection. Please visit [Differences between an array and any collection from the java Collection framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361489/differences-between-an-array-and-any-collection-from-the-java-collection-framewo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between an array and any collection from the java Collection framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361489/differences-between-an-array-and-any-collection-from-the-java-collection-framewo)

Comment: Each has its strengths and weaknesses. Many other programming languages have both too (Java was heavily inspired from C++, but has taken inspiration from many places).

Comment: plus only for the thinking. You learn most 1. you know and understand the language and then question why a feature was like this, would it have made some harm had this was not like waht it is in the langauge specification.

Comment: Agree with @nits.kk that the thinking is good. The question still isn’t well suited for a Stack Overflow question. My answer goes along: no, there wouldn’t be any real issue in not using arrays, but arrays were put in first, and they cannot take them out now since it would break the majority of programs already running in production (I tried to skip arrays when I taught, but the students met them elsewhere and asked, only for that reason I couldn’t).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed-size datatypes, which are supported by the JVM and provide features like random access.

`Collection` are not the same as arrays. There also are collections like `Set`s, which have different properties. In general, use an `ArrayList` if you want to have a dynamic growable list.

Answer (score 0):

There are many difference in arrays and collection in java some are:

1. A collection is growable in nature that is based on our requirement. We can increase or decrease in size. Whereas Arrays are fixed in size that is once we create an array we can not increase or decrease based on our requirement.
2. With respect to memory: a collection is more recommended whereas with respect to performance: an array is more recommended.
3. Arrays can hold only homogeneous elements but collections can hold both homogeneous and heterogeneous elements.
4. Arrays don't have ready-made methods but collections have ready-made data structures and methods.
5. Arrays can hold both primitives and wrapper objects but collections can hold only objects.

Below are some set of collections in java:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionExamples {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      List LinkedList = new LinkedList();
      LinkedList.add("Linked List Position 1");
      LinkedList.add("Linked List Position 2");
      LinkedList.add("Linked List Position 3");
      LinkedList.add("Linked List Position 4");
      displayAll(LinkedList);

      List arrayList = new ArrayList();
      arrayList.add("Array List Position 1");
      arrayList.add("Array List Position 2");
      arrayList.add("Array List Position 3");
      arrayList.add("Array List Position 4");
      displayAll(arrayList);

      Set hashSet = new HashSet();
      hashSet.add("Hashset Position 1");
      hashSet.add("Hashset Position 2");
      hashSet.add("Hashset Position 3");
      hashSet.add("Hashset Position 4");
      displayAll(hashSet);

      SortedSet treeSet = new TreeSet();
      treeSet.add("TreeSet Position 1");
      treeSet.add("TreeSet Position 2");
      treeSet.add("TreeSet Position 3");
      treeSet.add("TreeSet Position 4");
      displayAll(treeSet);

      LinkedHashSet linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet();
      linkedHashSet.add("linkedHashSet Position 1");
      linkedHashSet.add("linkedHashSet Position 2");
      linkedHashSet.add("linkedHashSet Position 3");
      linkedHashSet.add("linkedHashSet Position 4");
      displayAll(linkedHashSet);

      Map hashMap = new HashMap();
      hashMap.put("hashMapKey1", "hashMapValue1");
      hashMap.put("hashMapKey2", "hashMapValue2");
      hashMap.put("hashMapKey3", "hashMapValue3");
      hashMap.put("hashMapKey4", "hashMapValue4");
      displayAll(hashMap.keySet());
      displayAll(hashMap.values());

   }
   static void displayAll(Collection col) {
      Iterator itr = col.iterator();
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
         String str = (String) itr.next();
         System.out.println(str);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your point 2 doesn't make much sense, collections are usually more memory intensive than arrays (and usually collections use arrays as their building blocks).

Comment: Arrays are fixed in size, but Collections are dynamic in size. This is the reason why Collections are preferred over Arrays with respect to memory. read this for more info: https://dzone.com/articles/preventing-your-java-collections-from-wasting-memo, whereas Arrays are preferred over Collections when we see with the perspective of performance, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910470/collection-vs-array-performance-wise

Comment: Although you are right the collections are more flexible, the fact most of the collections are built on top of arrays pretty much invalidates the argument that collections are somehow 'better' for memory.

Answer (score 0):

Collections offer everything arrays do but more, with one exception. **Performance**.

Take a look at [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is the Collection version of the array.

ArrayList only supports Objects, not primitives. If you wanted to create an ArrayList of ints for each value you would add it would have to be autoboxed into an Integer, which is a significant overhead in performance.

[image]

If all you want is a simple data structure to store some stuff you don't need to take that hit in performance. But if you need to do some extra stuff like dynamically resizable arrays or Sets, java supports you by offering you Collections